# Any way to properly sort this array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have an array that has information from a file. the file contains population of various countries. The goal is to sort it from highest to lowest. The data has commas in it, which disables the option to convert to an int. for example: "10,979","2,313,973,713", "134" etc. This is the method I used to sort:

```
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
  for(j=1+i;j<length-1;j++){
    if(popList[i].compareTo(popList[j])>0)
    {
      temp2=popList[i];
      temp=countryList[i];
      popList[i]=popList[j];
      countryList[i]=countryList[j];
      popList[j]=temp2;
      countryList[j]=temp;
    }
  }    //
}
```

I end up with the output of:

```
    10,979
    134
    2,313,973,713
```

Is there a way to compare it fully with each digit being compared and sort it with the commas?

Comment: added a solution that proberly solves it based on strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*See edit for version that handles as int(can't handle over int.max)*

So in order to compare an n length of population, and given that the input can be seperated by "," and is always a String, this can sort the list as intended

```
public class Country implements Comparable<Country>{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        countries.add(new Country("10,979"));
        countries.add(new Country("2,313,973,713"));
        countries.add(new Country("134"));
        countries.add(new Country("321"));
        countries.add(new Country("52,851"));
        countries.add(new Country("134"));

        Collections.sort(countries);

        for(Country country : countries)
            System.out.println(country.getPopulation());
    }

    private String population;

    public Country(String population){
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(String population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Country o) { //will break unless input is numbers or "," seperated numbers
        String temp1 = population.replaceAll(",", "");
        String temp2 = o.population.replaceAll(",", "");

        if(temp1.length() > temp2.length())
            return 1;
        else if(temp2.length() > temp1.length())
            return -1;
        else
        {
            char[] pop1 = temp1.toCharArray();
            char[] pop2 = temp2.toCharArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < temp1.length(); i++){
                if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pop1[i])) > Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pop2[i])))
                    return 1;
                else if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pop1[i])) < Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pop2[i])))
                    return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this solution is very specific for this problem and also that the wrapper allows you to save various other data about a country, and sort based on multiple things if say population is the same maybe you want to sort on name or similar

The output is

> 134
>
> 134
>
> 321
>
> 10,979
>
> 52,851
>
> 2,313,973,713

Comment: Thank you! helped out a lot.

Comment: @GilLitvak no problem, glad it was usefull :)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace comma from String then compare as long.

```
str = str.replaceAll(",", "");
```